# Setting font of an ActiveX commandbutton

Tags: excel, excel-2013, activexobject, vba

I have an Excel spreadsheet, and I'm trying to set the font of an ActiveX commandbutton with this code:

```
With Worksheets("Schedule Tool").Shapes("CommandButton1")
    .Height = 31.4645669291
    .Width = 145.4173228346
    .Font = "Calibri"
    .Font.Size = 9
    .Left = 1017.75
    .Top = 130.5
End With
```

When it hits the `.Font` and `.Font.Size` bits, it breaks and says "Object doesn't support this property or method". I'm all right skipping `.Font`, but changing the size is critical.

I've tried googling it to find the correct properties for ActiveX commandbuttons (I assume I'm just using the wrong ones), but all I find is endless discussions of the old shrinking button glitch. Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
With Worksheets("Schedule Tool").Shapes("CommandButton1")
    .Height = 31.4645669291
    .Width = 145.4173228346
    With .DrawingObject.Object.Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .Size = 9
    End With
    .Left = 1017.75
    .Top = 130.5
End With
```

Comment: Works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

This sub will create ActiveX button. Font properties are not manageable through VBA program as far as I have knowledge. Font size are changed by going to design mode in Excel sheet, selecting command button and then from properties change Font size.

```
Sub createactive_button()
'

    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", Link:=False _
        , DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=1017.75, Top:=130.5, Width:=145.4173228346, Height:=31.4645669291 _
        ).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah, that's how I set them in the first place. I was hoping to automate a fix for the shrinking button bug, so I won't be there to fix it manually when users start having problems.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the Font settings to the Characters of the shape, so change those font lines to `.TextFrame.Characters.Font` and it should function as you expect

Comment: Not having any luck with any of those, I'm afraid - same error. Could the ActiveX commandbuttons be lacking textframes or something?

Comment: @AndrewPerry try instead using the `FontSize` property on the Object itself

Comment: No luck. I wonder if it might not be editable at all through VBA...? :-(

Comment: @Rory's solution worked - needed to dig down a bit into the object properties. Thanks for trying!